# Authentication error while making request using Fuel REST Client for Node.js

Tags: javascript, rest-api, api, fuel-sdk, node.js

I'm using FuelSDK-node-REST to make API requests by following instructions given here: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Node-REST. Upon running my code, i am getting an error. Below is my code and the error i receive.

```
const FuelRest = require("fuel-rest");

const options = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "CLIENT_ID_HERE",
    clientSecret: "CLIENT_SECRET_HERE",
    authUrl:
      "https://MY_AUTH_URL.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token/", //Tried without '/v2/token/' also
  },
  origin: "https://MY_ORIGIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/",
};

const RestClient = new FuelRest(options);

const getOpts = {
  uri: "/platform/v1/endpoints",
  headers: {},
  // other request options
};

RestClient.get(getOpts)
  .then(function (response) {
    var result = response && response.body ? response.body : response;
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

I get this error when i run my code:

```
{ Error: No access token
    at AuthClient.getAccessToken.then.tokenInfo (E:\Development\node-scripts\node_modules\fuel-rest\lib\fuel-rest.js:88:18)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
  res:
   { error: 'unsupported_grant_type',
     error_description: 'Use "authorization_code" or "refresh_token" or "client_credentials" or "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer" as the grant_type.',
     error_uri: 'https://developer.salesforce.com/docs' } }
```

I don't see any issues with permissions etc with the installed app in my account. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone else stumbles across this, I was missing `authOptions` in the rest client initialization. Below is the correct way to init the rest client.

```
const options = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "CLIENT_ID_HERE",
    clientSecret: "CLIENT_SECRET_HERE",
    authUrl:
      "https://MY_AUTH_URL.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token/", 
authOptions: {
      authVersion: 2,
    }
  },
  origin: "https://MY_ORIGIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/",
};

const RestClient = new FuelRest(options);
```